# SYNTAX for two COUNT questions?

Tags: sql, syntax

I am looking for the syntax to a) Count the number of sales by each person if they had less than 3 sales for the past period. I used [SELECT COUNT(SalesAmount),SalesPerson FROM SALES1 WHERE SalesAmount = < 3;] which is wrong.

I am also looking for the syntax to b) Find the number (count) of sales by each person, but only if they made less than or equal to £300 worth of sales for the past period.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> SELECT SalesPerson, SUM(SalesAmount), count(*) as NumberSales
>  FROM SALES1 
> GRUOP BY SalesPerson    HAVING count(*) < 3;
> ```

> ```
>   SELECT SalesPerson, SUM(SalesAmount), count(*) as NumberSales
>  FROM SALES1 
> GRUOP BY SalesPerson    HAVING SUM(SalesAmount) <= 300;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to pre-query per sales person on the week basis withouto respect to the why.  Only after that, this will become the basis of the secodary qualifications you are asking.  Also, what defines a "period"?  Is it per week, per month?  With such low numbers, I will assume it is per week from your data.

So my alias PQ (pre-query) is doing the aggregation per sales person per week.  That is used for the final

```
select
      sum( case when PQ.weekCount <= 3 then 1 else 0 end ) CountLessThan3,
      sum( case when PQ.weekSales <= 300 then 1 else 0 end ) SalesLessThan300
   from
      ( select
              salesPerson,
              week,
              count(*) weekCount,
              sum( salesAmount ) weekSales
           from
              YourTable
           group by
              salesPerson,
              week ) PQ
```

Now, if you wanted to know who qualified under these low performing numbers, you might want to alter to something like below using a HAVING clause which is applied AFTER the group by condition

```
select
      salesPerson,
      week,
      count(*) weekCount,
      sum( salesAmount ) weekSales
   from
      YourTable
   group by
      salesPerson,
      week
   having
         count(*) <= 3
      OR sum( salesAmount ) <= 300
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
-- Count the number of sales by each person if they had more than or equal to 2 sales for past period:

```sql
SELECT s.salesperson, COUNT(DISTINCT s.salesamount)
FROM SALES1 s
GROUP BY s.salesperson
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.salesamount) >= 2;
```

-- Find the number of sales by each person but only if they made $300 worth of sales for the past period:

```sql
SELECT s.salesperson, sum(s.salesamount), COUNT(DISTINCT s.salesamount)
FROM SALES1 s
GROUP BY s.salesperson
HAVING sum(s.salesamount) < 300;
```